# How to limit the number of pages shown in pagination in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, pagination

I am developing a web application using MERN stack. I have implemented pagination using React & Bootstrap.
[image]
[image]

**WHAT DO I WANT?**
Currently, I have a limited data set. So, the number of pages shown in the pagination are manageable. But with a larger data set, I should be able to limit the number of pages shown in the pagination. The result I am looking for is the pagination implemented at the site [www.flanker.net](https://flanker.net/).
[image]

The following are my code snippets.
**components/Movies.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import MoviesTable from "./MoviesTable";
import { fetchMovies } from "./moviesSlice";
import "./Movies.css";
import Pagination from "./common/Pagination";
import { paginate } from "./../utils/paginate";

const Movies = () => {
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(4);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchMovies());
  }, [dispatch]);

  const handlePageChange = (page) => {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  };
  const handlePreviousClick = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
  };
  const handleNextClick = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  const { status, movies } = useSelector((state) => state.movies);

  const paginatedMovies = paginate(movies, currentPage, pageSize);

  let content;

  if (status === "loading") {
    content = (
      <div className="spinner">
        <div className="spinner-border text-success">
          <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    content = (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-xs-10 col-md-8 mx-auto mt-3">
          {paginatedMovies.length > 0 ? (
            <MoviesTable movies={paginatedMovies} />
          ) : null}
          <Pagination
            itemsCount={movies.length}
            pageSize={pageSize}
            currentPage={currentPage}
            onPageChange={handlePageChange}
            onPreviousClick={handlePreviousClick}
            onNextClick={handleNextClick}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return <>{content}</>;
};

export default Movies;
```

**components/pagination.js**

```
import React from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

const Pagination = ({
  itemsCount,
  pageSize,
  onPageChange,
  currentPage,
  onPreviousClick,
  onNextClick,
}) => {
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(itemsCount / pageSize);
  if (pageCount === 1) return null;
  const pages = _.range(1, pageCount + 1);

  return (
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
      <ul className="pagination">
        {currentPage !== 1 && (
          <li class="page-item">
            <a
              className="page-link"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={onPreviousClick}
            >
              Previous
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
        {pages.map((page) => (
          <li
            key={page}
            className={page === currentPage ? "page-item active" : "page-item"}
          >
            <a
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              className="page-link"
              onClick={() => onPageChange(page)}
            >
              {page}
            </a>
          </li>
        ))}
        {currentPage !== pageCount && (
          <li class="page-item">
            <a
              className="page-link"
              style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
              onClick={onNextClick}
            >
              Next
            </a>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Pagination;
```

**src/utils/paginate.js**

```
import _ from "lodash";

export function paginate(items, pageNumber, pageSize) {
  const startIndex = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
  return _(items).slice(startIndex).take(pageSize).value();
}
```

I did some research in the internet, but could not find a solution. I don't know where to start. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems and I resolved them with this algorithm :

```
     handleClick(event) {
            this.TotalPage();
            this.setState({
                currentPage: Number(event.target.id)
            });
        }

 const pageNumbers = 10;
 ShowPaginationNumbers(pageNumbers) {

    let paginationNumbers = [];

    if (pageNumbers) {
        let showMax = 3;
        let endPage;
        let startPage;

        if (pageNumbers <= showMax) {
            startPage = 1;
            endPage = pageNumbers.length;
        }
        else {
            startPage = this.state.currentPage;
            if (startPage != pageNumbers.length && (startPage + 1) != pageNumbers.length) {
                endPage = this.state.currentPage + showMax - 1;
            }
            else {
                endPage = pageNumbers.length;
            }
        }
        for (let i = startPage; i <= endPage; i++) {
            paginationNumbers.push(i);
        }
        return this.ShowRenderPageNumbers(paginationNumbers); 
    }
}


    ShowRenderPageNumbers(paginationNumbers) {

        if (paginationNumbers) {
          let result = paginationNumbers.map(number => {
                return (
                    <li className="page-item" >
                        <a className={(this.state.currentPage === number ? ' active' : '') + ' page-link'} key={number} id={number} onClick={this.handleClick}>{number}</a>
                    </li>
                );
          });
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I really hope not to bother you after this long but would you be willing to help me out with this issue? I'm trying to do the same the OP asked but I'm having troubles LOL.